# When Data part will be merge

Tags: clickhouse

I'm use CollapsingMergeTree engine to update data follow doc (https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/table_engines/collapsingmergetree/#collapsing)

Base on document:

> CollapsingMergeTree asynchronously deletes (collapses) pairs of rows if all of the fields in a row are equivalent excepting the particular field Sign which can have 1 and -1 values

And

> As we need only the last state of user activity, the rows [....]
>   can be deleted collapsing the invalid (old) state of an object. CollapsingMergeTree does this while merging of the data parts.

Can I know when Data parts will be merge ? And is there command to force Clickhouse to merge data part ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I know when Data parts will be merge ?

ClickHouse schedule asynchronous jobs in indeterministic ways. See https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/blob/master/dbms/src/Storages/MergeTree/BackgroundProcessingPool.cpp#L29

Those jobs include `data parts clean up`, `data parts merge` and `data parts mutation`.

> And is there command to force Clickhouse to merge data part ?

Yes, https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/misc/#optimize

Comment: By mistaken, i'm insert recod with wrong Sign value (ex: 10). How can I delete this record ? I'm tried to insert Cancel row (Sign=-10) and execute OPTIMIZE, but DB::Exception: Incorrect data: Sign = 10 (must be 1 or -1).

Comment: You cannot modify the `Sign` column (key column is immutable in ClickHouse for now). Just do an `INSERT INTO new_table SELECT ..., case Sign when 10 then 1 when -10 then -1 else whatever end as Sign from old_table`.